# hlsl syntax conditional expression

Tags: 3d, hlsl

In the book "Programming Vertex, Geometry, and Pixel Shaders" there is a small hlsl-script with the following instruction:

return (x != y != z);

Is this really allowed? Is this syntactically correct? What does this mean?

return (x != y && y != z);?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(x != y != z)` is not the same as `(x != y && y != z)`. In general, [hlsl](/questions/tagged/hlsl) follows the same rules as [c](/questions/tagged/c).  In this case, the left-to-right rule applies for the `!=` operator.  Assuming the values are integers, the expression `(x != y != z)` is equivalent to the following:

```
int temp = (x != y); // true = 1, false = 0
int r = (temp != z); // true = 1, false = 0
```

As a result, the expression will evaluate to `1` if and only if `x` and `y` are equal and `z` is not `0`, or if `x` and `y` are not equal and `z` is not `1`.

If the values are `bool`s or can guaranteed to be either `0` or `1`, the expression reduces to the logical exclusive-or (xor) of the three terms.